# inject connection string with code in database first in EF6

Tags: winforms, entity-framework-6, connection-string, ef-database-first, dll-injection

I have several project in my solution and you think there are prjBook and prjLibrary.
I install EF6 on prjBook and added it(prjBook) to prjLibrary as Reference. when run prjBook alone, everything ok and successfully select and get data but when run from prjLibrary it shows error:"can't find connection string."
i know this error for it isn't any field of connection string in app config of prjLibrary .
my question clearly is how could i inject connection string of prjBook project to prjLibrary project? for example inject connection string  with cod to dbContex of prjBook

Comment: public BookDBEntities()
            : base("metadata=res://*/BookDataMdel.csdl|res://*/BokDataMdel.ssdl|res://*/BookDataMdel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=BookDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;")
        {
        }

Comment: still has same error. nobody has an idea??